# Tastypie limit user to create more resources

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a subscription service online app. If the user has payed he may create as many resources as he want, if not he would be limited.

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    current_user = auth.get_user(bundle.request)
    if current_user.get_profile().has_payed:
        return super(ClientResource, self).obj_create(bundle, user=current_user)
    else:
        if Client.objects.filter(user=current_user).count() < 2:
            print "you may create"
            return super(ClientResource, self).obj_create(bundle, user=current_user)
        else:
            return ???
```

Is this the correct way? And what do I need to return to tell the user the custom message of "Sorry you have reached the limit, please pay up"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you simply return a 401 (unauthorized) http response. Its the RESTFul thing to do